# Python: How to instantiate an object, then access it in imported module?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming, trying to make a basic text-based game. I have a central 'hub' which imports modules for character creation and things like fighting and visiting markets. My question is this:

I instantiate an object 'player' from class 'Player' in the hub script. I then import the 'shops' script, which has to be able to read and edit the 'player' object's attributes. But when I run the hub script I get:

```
NameError: name 'player' is not defined
```

I realise this is probably because 'player' was instantiated in the hub script, and so the imported shops module can't read or edit it. Is there any way I can make an object accessible, not just to the script it's in, but to the modules imported into that script? Thanks!

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward way would be to pass it as an argument to whatever functions you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly check:
http://wiki.python-ogre.org/index.php?title=Game_State_Management

Read about Singletons.